# complexity for a nested loop with growing internal loop

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am confused to the time complexity of this piece of code and the logic used to find it.

```
void doit(int N) {
    for (int k = 1; k < N; k *= 2) { <----I am guessing this runs O(logN)
           for (int j = 1; j < k; j += 1) { <------I am not sure how this one works.
       }
    }
}
```

I have already tried solving it out by hand writing it out. But, I still don't understand it.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Adding another question to it. Same concept, different format.

```
void doit(int N) {
    int j, k; //I ended up getting this answer to be O(n^(n/2)) But then I was stuck after that...is that even the right answer?
    for (k = 1; k < N / 2; k += 1) {
       for (j = k; j < 2 * k; j += 1) [
             x[j] = x[j-k] + x[j];//This doesn't really matter
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The total complexity is actually `O(N)`

**Claim:** For each `k` you have `k` inner loop iterations. (convince yourself why it is correct)

**Denote** the number of total inner loops iterations by `T(N)`, and let the number of outer loops be `h`. 

This means we have:

```
T(N) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^h 
     < 2 * 2^h               (1)
     = 2^(h+1)     
     = 2^(logN + 1)          (2)
     = 2^(log(2N))   
     = 2N
```

---

(1) From [sum or geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)

(2) Note that the equality `2^(h+1) = 2^(logN + 1)` is because `h = logN`, we have (as you said) `logN` outer loop iterations.

Comment: I added another question...same format but different loop growths, I am stuck on finding the answer here. Can you please help me out? thank you in advance

Comment: @bluejamesbond: You should ask new questions as new quetions, and not edit. However - Note that in the second case the number of inner loops iterations `T(n) = (2-1) + (4-2) + (6-3) + ... (N-N/2) =  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + (N/2)` which is `O(N^2)` from sum of arithmetic progression.

Comment: yes I will. woahh! how did you figure that out? how do you learn this?

Comment: @bluejamesbond: some math background before starting to learn algorithms is helpful, but mostly - experience.

Comment: are there any online practice problems where i can just go down a list of them and see if i have the correct answer? or similar.

Comment: I would be obliged if you can help me with this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838178/uniform-hashing-functions I really need to study for an upcoming test. Thank you in advance.